# inline-block div element doesn't wrap around other inline-block elements

Tags: css

I styled websites before but this time I'm in a complete loss. I'm banging my head with this for last couple of hours (no exaggeration here). I need a parent DIV with white background to wrap dynamically generated (through php or ajax call) DIV's. This way I can create the design as I wanted it (1px white space between images).

Here is a jsFiddle I set up, if anyone have time too look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/5eJjy/

And here is a "live" version: http://developer.sodobniinternet.eu/es-photo/

Problem: the `div.images` with no width and `display:inline-block` expands to his parent's width. With my experiences with CSS, DIV with inline-block should wrap around containing elements, but it doesn't.

Tried: removing width of `div.items`, removing all css one by one, putting only the part with issues in another file and tried to make it work (and sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't).

Expected result: `div.images` to wrap all `div.imgContainer` with 1px space between `div.imgContainer` and 1px white border around `div.images` container (actually faking the borders with 1px padding).

I have created screenshot of whats wrong and how do I want it:

wrong: http://shrani.si/f/2r/d0/1K6RkAyH/no.jpg

expected: http://shrani.si/f/3F/pw/Egu9OES/expected.jpg

Thank you for your time and help.

**EDIT: I have updated the expected result. I noticed that I didn't wrote it properly.**

**Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ebF8q/**

I removed the `div.images`, set to parent div `font-size:0` (to remove unwanted space), to `div.imgContainer` I added/updated `border: 1px solid #fff; margin: 0 -1px -1px 0px;` and I got the desired result. Screenshot: http://shrani.si/f/2C/pi/2T0FUvWD/done.jpg

Comment: Why does it need to be an inline-block? Having it as default display of block seems to work fine. Your live site seems fine the way it is.

Comment: Where, on `div.images`? I tried that many times, it's not OK. Maybe you got just the right resolution, but it isn't OK. Please, see the screenshot attachments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've achieved a strange hack :
http://jsfiddle.net/CGPBM/

You remove the div.images background, add a border to div.imgContainer and set margin to -1px -1px

```
.images {    
    font-size: 0px;
}

.imgContainer {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 188px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: -1px -1px;
}
```

But it has to be tested on several resolutions (JSfiddle is so small ...)

I also applied it to your website, and there is a white space you need to get rid of between
`<div class="imgContainer"></div><div class="imgContainer"></div><div class="imgContainer"></div>`

Comment: I don't see the difference between original example and yours. Btw, original one is even better, yours is flickering then resizing.

Comment: Neither did I, but it gave me an idea or I should say it, a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some things with CSS, but couldn't get it to work. This is an approach using only JS:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.items').css('width', ($('#content').innerWidth() - (parseInt($('.filters').width()) + parseInt($('.filters').css('padding-left')) + parseInt($('.filters').css('padding-right')) + parseInt($('.filters').css('margin-left')) + parseInt($('.filters').css('margin-right'))) - 2) + 'px');
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    // original container size
    var consize = $('#content').innerWidth() - (parseInt($('.filters').width()) + parseInt($('.filters').css('padding-left')) + parseInt($('.filters').css('padding-right')) + parseInt($('.filters').css('margin-left')) + parseInt($('.filters').css('margin-right'))) - 2;
    // size of single contained image
    var imgsize = $('.imgContainer').outerWidth(true);
    // difference of full (max) and wanted size
    var margin = consize % imgsize;
    // set size/margin, so that wraps max number of images
    $('.items').css('width', (consize - margin + 1) + 'px');
    $('.items').css('margin-right', margin + 'px');
});
```